# how to add userid on session data in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added the username in session like this

```
if($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE){
            //validation pass
            $res = $this->Admin_model->verify_user($this->input->post('email_address'), $this->input->post('password'), $this->_salt);

            //if result is true login
            if($res !== false){
                //person has account
                $_SESSION['username'] = $this->input->post('email_address');
```

Now how do i add user_id in a session after user login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **SHOULD** use CodeIgniter [Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) like `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id', $row['user_id']);` forget about raw sessions (and other global arrays usage)

Comment: it's more flexible, offering flashdata/session encryption, user-agent matching and so on

Comment: He's right, the main functional reason is to store your sessions in a database instead of in the browser / cookies. This way you can safely-ish store things you don't want the user to see. The session class does this for you (take a look at his link for details on setting it up). Also you are using a framework precisely so you don't have to reinvent the wheel - you should learn how to use it properly otherwise it will just get in your way.

Comment: @Louis As far as I know the only thing php native session stores in cookies is the session id. And I have a feeling this happens also for codeigniter sessions. No userdata is stored in cookies. But the flashdata/encryption stuff is a good point though. Thanks